# For Loop is slow - Java

Tags: java, pdfbox

I basically want to load a pdf using Apache pdfbox and convert it into a List of base64 for each page.

I tried the following code but it's extremely slow. I dont need to convert into an image, I just want to convert into base64 to pass to the frontend

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.loadNonSeq(new File("Random.pdf"), null);
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<PDPage> pdPages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
int page = 0;
List<String> base64DocumentPages = new ArrayList<>();
for (PDPage pdPage : pdPages)
{ 
    ++page;           
    BufferedImage img = pdPage.convertToImage(BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB, 300); // this is slow
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIOUtil.writeImage(img, ".png", os);
    String base64Page = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(os.toByteArray());
    base64DocumentPages.add(URLEncoder.encode(base64Page, "UTF-8"));
}
document.close();
```

I'm using PDFBOX to loop the pages but I can use anything if you know anything better.

PS: I really need the Base64 data of the pages separated in some sort of array

Comment: Please define extremely slow.

Comment: @JasonArmstrong 15 seconds

Comment: For how many pages?

Comment: 8. This should be faster

Comment: It's not the loop that is slow. Converting to a 300dpi image will take some time. Choose a smaller dpi. If you want to have PDFs with a single page, then create a new PDF with that page and save that one. Also make sure you're using the latest PDFBox version, which is 2.0.13. You are using 1.8.* which has flaws with rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure its the `convertToImage` method? In our case it was the `writeImage` method which needs the longest.
The problem is that you use the standard PNGWriter. This one has a deficiency/bug that it always uses the the best compression on the cost of time. This has been fixed for Java 9 but until then there is a [backported](https://github.com/gredler/jdk9-png-writer-backport) version available. So what do you need to do?

(1) Add the following dependency to your maven projet (or manually if you don't use maven)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.gredler</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdk9-png-writer-backport</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

(2) Make sure you use PdfBox 2.X

(3) Change your conversion code:

```
private static void convertMethod2(File pdf) {
        try (final PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(pdf)) {
            PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(document);
            List<String> base64DocumentPages = new ArrayList<>();               

            for (int page = 0; page < document.getNumberOfPages(); ++page) {
                BufferedImage bim = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(page, 150, ImageType.RGB);
                
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                PNGImageWriterBackport writer = chosePngWriter();
            
                if(writer!=null) {
                    try (ImageOutputStream stream = new MemoryCacheImageOutputStream(baos)) {
                        writer.setOutput(stream);
                        writer.write(null,new IIOImage(bim, null, null), getImageParams(writer));
                    }
                    finally {
                        writer.dispose();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    System.err.println("PNGImageWriterBackport not found! Aborting");
                }
                String base64Page = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(os.toByteArray());
                base64DocumentPages.add(URLEncoder.encode(base64Page, "UTF-8"));
            }
            document.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            //handle exception
        }
    }
    
    private static PNGImageWriterBackport chosePngWriter() {
        Iterator<ImageWriter> imageWriters = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("png");
        
        ImageWriter writer = null;
        while(imageWriters.hasNext()) {
        
            writer = imageWriters.next();
            if (writer instanceof PNGImageWriterBackport) {
                return (PNGImageWriterBackport)writer;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    private static ImageWriteParam getImageParams(PNGImageWriterBackport writer) {
        ImageWriteParam writeParam = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
        //set compression mode which wasn't possible before
        writeParam.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
        //0.0f highest compression, slowest
        //1.0f lowest compression, fastest
        writeParam.setCompressionQuality(0.86f);
        
        return writeParam;
    }
```

(4) Of course if it is possible to reduce the DPI to e.g. 150 it would also speed up the process. But I know that this is not always possible...

This will be a lot faster for the price of a minimally increased png file size...